# (Android - Kotlin) - How to recover a button from included layout into fragment using view binding?

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener, android-viewbinding, android-include

I've created a specific layout in order to display when any internet error appears in my android application. 
The idea is to include this layout in the fragments where it can be a problem. This is the xml file:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/errorLayout">

    <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/error_24" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/textView24"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/fit_space"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/error_loading"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorOnPrimary"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/textView26"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/try_again"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorOnPrimary"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView24" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonRefresh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/refresh_24"
        android:text="@string/refresh"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView26" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm trying unsuccessfully to use the button from this layout in my fragment, which I included like that:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layoutContainerNews">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/errorLayoutNews"
        layout="@layout/item_layout_error"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <...content...>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm able to show and hide the layout normally, but I'm not able to reach successfully the button included in order to perform a click. 
This is one of the many ways that I tried, unsuccessfully, to perform a click in the button.

```
private fun configButtonRefreshClickListener() = with(binding) {
        val refreshButton = errorLayoutNews.buttonRefresh
        refreshButton.setOnClickListener {
            newsAdapter.refresh()
        }
    }
```

How could I access this button properly in order to perform the click? 
Thanks in advance. \

EDIT: I'm able, from the function above, using the same structure, to change the text from the textView but I'm not able to perform a click in the button.

```
val errorLayout = errorLayoutNews
errorLayout.textView19.text = "Test"
```

Comment: Maybe give the top level view of your reusable layout an ID?

Comment: It already have.. its named errorLayout.